# Foundation 6 nested grid with images not expanding full height

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a layout using WP and Foundation 6 grid. I have been fighting with this layout for days. The problem is that the images are not filling up 100% of their space. See codepen link below and attached screenshot. I am new to foundation so it is possible my syntax is off. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
You can see my code here:

https://codepen.io/enigmas2/pen/vgdxZo

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="row collapse" id="features" data-equalizer="features">    
           <div class="large-5 columns" data-equalizer-watch="features">
            <div class="row collapse">
              <div class="large-12 columns" id="welcome">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/548x227">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row collapse">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/548x459">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="large-7 columns" data-equalizer-watch="features">
            <div class="row collapse">
              <div class="large-12 columns">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/812x459">
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row collapse">
              <div class="large-6 columns">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/406x227">
              </div>
              <div class="large-6 columns">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/406x227">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--end features -->
        </div> <!-- end #inner-content -->
```

Comment: "breaks in FX and IE" can't be any less descriptive of the actual problem. Especially when it looks identical in chrome and firefox.

Comment: I posted a link to codepen, sorry didn't realize it wasn't showing the issue. I will update.

Comment: It's alright, it isn't so much about showing the issue as it is about you including a full description of the problem or even a screenshot.

Comment: I have updated my description with a screenshot.

Comment: Will this layout aways stay like this or do you want to be able to change things around in the future? I'm asking because if it's staying like this, you can probably do it with set values. If you need this to be dynamic then you will have to look at js masonry.

Comment: It can stay like this. But I will check into masonry.

Comment: Alright, up to you if you want to see a css solution but I won't bother if you're fine with other options.

Comment: A css solution would be wonderful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134617/discussion-between-johanna-and-serg-chernata).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty, I built this out using `flexbox`. You will notice one panel has a slightly larger gap. This has something to do with the pixel count after scaling down the images. There's basically no even way to divide the space so one section is a pixel shorter. You can try tweaking the images by a pixel or two and see if they end up fitting evenly.

I also built in a simple media query that will un-tile the images and display them in one column. If that's something you want to do. Otherwise, they stay tiled and keep shrinking.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .flex-column, .flex-row{
        display: block;
    }
    img{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggegzd?editors=1100#0

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Truly Serg, you are amazing!